# Losing width 100% when toggle visibility of table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have set the start of my table like this

```
<table class="table" width="100%" id="table_details['.$i.']" style="display:none">
```

And there is a working function to toggle the visibility this table.

```
function expand_table(selectVeld, nr)
{
    var div = document.getElementById('table_details['+nr+']');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('table_details_glyp['+nr+']').className = "fas fa-angle-up pull-right";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('table_details_glyp['+nr+']').className = "fas fa-angle-down pull-right";
    }
}
```

The table should like this when visible
[image]

For some reason the table is not expanding to 100% when making it visible
[image]

The same problem occurs when I put this function in a `div` and place the table in this `div`.
Any suggestions to stretch the table to 100%?

Comment: some good practices: don't use div as a variable name that stores table element. don't use inline styles. There's nothing in the code you've shown, AFAIK, that could change table width. Maybe problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are Using Bootstrap You can use col-md-12 before table.

If not Please expand parent div width to 100%

```
.parentDiv
{
 width:100%;
 float: left;
}
```